# Inconsistent behaviour with instance_eval

Tags: ruby

When passing a block to instance_eval, it is meant to be executed within the context of that instance. *self*, when referenced either explicitly or implicitly within that block, should refer to the instance that instance_eval has been called on. This seems to work fine in all cases, except when passing a method object that has been converted to a proc. In this case, *self* refers to the instance that the method is defined on, rather than the instance where the block is evaluated. Here's a code example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
class A
  def test(&b)
    instance_eval(&b)
  end
end

class B
  def test_a(a)
    a.test { puts self }
  end

  def test_b_helper(*args)
    puts self
  end

  def test_b(a)
    m = method(:test_b_helper).to_proc
    a.test(&m)
  end
end

a = A.new
b = B.new

b.test_a(a) #<A:0x007ff66b086c68>
b.test_b(a) #<B:0x007fa3e1886bc0>
```

The expected behaviour is for both tests to return the same output. In this case, *self* should refer to an instance of A, not B.

I have looked in the docs and done some searches, but I have not been able to find information on this peculiarity. I am hoping that there are some experienced Rubyists who can help clear up this difference in behaviour.

Just to clarify, I am using Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is, that Blocks and Procs are *closures*, Method objects are not.

Excerpt from D. Flanagan, Y. Matsumoto. *The Ruby Programming Language*, O'Reilly 2008, p. 204:

> One important difference between `Method` objects and `Proc` objects is
>   that Method objects are not closures. Ruby’s methods are intended to
>   be completely self-contained, and they never have access to local
>   variables outside of their own scope. The only binding retained by a
>   `Method` object, therefore, is the value of `self` — the object on which the
>   method is to be invoked.

When you now cast the Method object `to_proc`, you bind the value of `self` to the calling instance of B, hence you get the result you described above. Actually, `self` is already fixed when you create the `Method` object.

This gets particularly clear when you consider the following code:

```
class A
  def foo
    puts 'bar'
  end
end

class B; end

class C < A; end

foo = A.instance_method(:foo)
# => #<UnboundMethod: A#foo>

a = A.new
foo.bind(a).call
# bar

b = B.new
foo.bind(b).call
# TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of A

c = C.new
foo.bind(c).call
# bar
```

Simply put: `self` is always fixed on `Method` and `UnboundMethod` objects.

Comment: @tabdulla: added a clarifying example to my answer.